# How to use querySelector to select this element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="parentDiv" >
   <button class="close" 
    data-dismiss="modal" 
    style="..." 
    aria-label="Close" 
    onclick='$(this).closest(".parentDiv").remove()'
    >
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle small"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ errorMsg }}</div>
</div>
...
...
```

In the above sample code, what strategy can I use to change the jQuery $(this) to pure javascript code like using querySelector?

*Please note that I want to use Element.closest() because there will be many Div elements stacked on top of each other having "parentDiv" class name.*

Basically, I want to select the parent and then remove that node after the cick on $(this) element.

So what's the best approach for doing this without using jQuery selector like **$(this).closest('.parentDiv').remove()** ?

And is it possible to do it without knowing the class name or ID of the current (this) element ?

Comment: Which element are you trying to target? `.parentDiv`? Surely it would just be `document.querySelector('.parentDiv')` that you're looking for then?

Comment: Great! So if I do document.querySelector('.parentDiv') would it automatically give me the closest one ? Because there are several divs stacked on top of each other with parentDiv class name. (OK  I am checking right now.)

Comment: No it does not. It is relative to document

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're trying to do now. Yep, you're looking for `.parentNode`.

Comment: Try this polyfill for closest https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: Easiest way is just to add `id` to element that you want to remove. Then you can do `onclick="document.getElementById('parentId').remove()"`

Comment: Sorry,  this HTML is rendered using Server Side and I do not want to use ID or class if possible for every button. Just want to use the onclick on the current element if possible and doable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a button is always nested in a `parentDiv` container just grab the parent node and remove it using `parentNode` and `remove`.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
   this.parentNode.remove();
});
```

```html
<div>
<button>remove me</button>
</div>
```

Within an onclick :

```html
<div>
<button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">remove me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the `remove()` method isn't available in Internet Explorer, but you can use the polyfill at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Comment: This isn't JQuery, it's just Vanilla JS. `this` is a keyword in JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) property of your element.
It will be without a usage of the class selector.

The code will be:

```
if (node.parentNode) {
  // remove a node from the tree, unless 
  // it's not in the tree already
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why jQuery was created.  Below is the equivalent JavaScript, which would handle multiple buttons, in which any of their ancestors (parent, grandparent, etc.) has the `parentDiv` class

```
// JS equivalent to $(this).closest('.parentDiv').remove()

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.close');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var parent = this.parentNode;

    while (!parent.classList.contains('parentDiv')) {
      parent = parent.parentNode;
    }

    parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
  });
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.close');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var parent = this.parentNode;

    while (!parent.classList.contains('parentDiv')) {
      parent = parent.parentNode;
    }

    parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
  });
}
```

```css
.parentDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  Parent 1
  <button class="close">
    Delete Parent 1
  </button>
</div>

<div class="parentDiv">
  Parent 2
  <span>
    <button class="close">
      Delete Parent 2
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you change your HTML and your button isn't the direct nested child of the node you want to remove, then potentially you you can just get rid of the jquery selector, with a minor caveat. Instead of `$(this)` just use `this`.

[Element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) has decent browser support (except for internet explorer), and if you're truly worried about browser support then there is also a polyfill.

Essentially one purpose of jquery is to enable standardized methods across browsers that might not support them yet, such as Element.closest. Unfortunately if you want full browser support, I don't think there's a one liner you can use to replace your statement using jquery. However, you can include only the parts you need, such as the Element.closest polyfill in a script tag (perhaps in the head of your html document).

```html
<script>
// Optional Element.closest polyfill
if (!Element.prototype.matches)
    Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
                                Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;

if (!Element.prototype.closest){
    Element.prototype.closest = function(s) {
        var el = this;
        if (!document.documentElement.contains(el)) return null;
        do {
            if (el.matches(s)) return el;
            el = el.parentElement || el.parentNode;
        } while (el !== null && el.nodeType === 1); 
        return null;
    };
}

</script>

<div class="parentDiv" >
   <button class="close" 
    data-dismiss="modal" 
    style="..." 
    aria-label="Close" 
    onclick='this.closest(".parentDiv").remove()'
    >
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle small">Remove</span>
    </button>

    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ errorMsg }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `closest()` method isn't available in Internet Explorer, but you can use the polyfill at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest